# Optional Parameters, No overload for 'Employee' matches delegate 'System.Func<Employee>

Tags: c#, generics

When trying to invoke a delegate which reference a function with optional parameter, iam getting
No overload for 'Employee' matches delegate 'System.Func

Then how to call it, when i don't need to pass the parameter.

```
    Func<Employee> print = Employee;
    Employee employee = print();

    private Employee Employee(int employeeID = 1)
    {
        return new Employee();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Func<Employee> print = () => Employee(pi)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with delegates providing the optional parameters.

```
 delegate Employee Print (int arg = 1);

 Print  EmployeeMethod = Employee;
 EmployeeMethod();
```

Func and Action cannot support optional parameters or rather they are not defined that way.

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

Answer (score 1):

The optional parameter doesn't change the method signature.  You are trying to convert a method with one parameter to a delegate with no parameters - they are not compatible.

You can use a lambda that will delegate to your method making use of the default value for the optional parameter:

```
Func<Employee> print = () => Employee();
Employee employee = print();
```