# Linq .Select() / .SelectMany() automatically uses second, optional parameter

Tags: c#, linq, select, optional-parameters

I just found the weirdest behavior in Linq:

When calling unary functions I like to just pass the function name, so instead of

```
var foo = myList.Select(item => MyFunc(item));
```

I write

```
var foo = myList.Select(MyFunc);
```

which should be the same. Only in some cases, it isn't! Namely if the function has a second parameter which is an `int` and optional:

```
private string MyFunc(string input, int foo = 0)
{
   ...
}
```

In this case, the statement

```
var foo = myList.Select(MyFunc);
```

equals

```
var foo = myList.Select((item, index) => MyFunc(item, index));
```

If the second parameter is either not opional or not an `int`, the compiler complains, but in this case, it just sneakily surprises you.

Has anyone else encountered this? Which other Linq expressions work this way? (so far, `.SelectMany()` does). And what is the most elegant way to work around this behavior (and keep others from falling into the same trap?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an issue of specific LINQ extension method, but how optional parameters are handled for `Func`s and `Action`s, in short - they are not, they are considered a regular parameter and default value is omitted when selecting a corresponding `Func`/`Action` signature. Take a look here [Optional Parameters, No overload for 'Employee' matches delegate 'System.Func<Employee>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740766/optional-parameters-no-overload-for-employee-matches-delegate-system-funcem) or here [Invoke Func<T1, T2, T3> which has optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828767/invoke-funct1-t2-t3-which-has-optional-parameters).

In other words, your `MyFunc` cannot be used as `Func<string, string>`, you must use `Func<string, int, string>`, which in case of `Select` happens to be present as an overload with index added.